# I'm trying to make a discord bot give roles base on the time since somebody has joined the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm pretty new to discord.js but I'm trying to make a bot give roles based on time elapsed since the user joined (the bot's role is above the needed roles and the bot itself has admin permissions)

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.roles.add(801917861110874122);
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(Date.now() - message.member.joinedAt < 1000*60*60*24*1) {
        message.member.roles.add(801917434558808074);
    }
});
```

Basically, the bot doesn't give the role neither when the user joins nor when the wanted amount of time passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a role to `.add()`, which can be done by looking up the ID from the cache.

Here is an example:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("801917861110874122");
member.roles.add(role);
```

You can also search through roles using the name instead of the ID like this:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Role name");
member.roles.add(role);
```

Edit:

To make your time function work, you need to use `message.member.joinedTimestamp` instead of `message.member.joinedAt`, like this:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(Date.now() - message.member.joinedTimestamp < 1000*60*60*24*1) {
        message.member.roles.add(801917434558808074);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you the role giving now works but I still have a problem with the time part 
the 

`if(Date.now() - message.member.joinedAt < 1000*60*60*24*1)`

still doesn't trigger.
Also, is there a way to generalize the role cache? (like to get the roles as a general variable so that I can easily use them again?)

Comment: I'm not actually sure why the time isn't working, are you able to log `Date.now()` and `message.member.joinedAt` for me? You could generalise the role cache, but it's probably better to just use `message.guild.roles.cache` each time to be honest, as that way it's always "up to date" - but if you really wanted to you could put `let roles = message.guild.roles.cache` at the top of your `message` listener, however just remember that `guild` won't be present if the bot receives a DM

Comment: ok so basically your answer led me to the solution because for some reason message.member.joinedAt didn't return a numerical value so I tried message.member.joinedTimestamp and that returned the needed value with which I can now do the task